# PHP Timestamp Hour issue

Tags: php, timestamp, hour

Currently I'm creating a website that also creates logs. The problem is, is the time stamps. Everything but the Hour is reading correctly.

Code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d, g:i:s a');
$sql = "INSERT INTO logs (ip, date, page) VALUES ('$ip', '$date', '$page')";
```

Currently it is 6:41 PM and this is what its reading (The minutes and seconds are accurate)

[image]

Comment: 1. it's a bad practice to store a date column not in `date/datetime` type column 2. What do you know about timezones?

Comment: I strongly recommend date field in DB to be bigint, so you can put there time() instead of date(). It's DB independent and problemless. You can then read date like date('FORMAT',$TS_FROM_DB)

Comment: this is running on my personal machine. As far as I know it should grab my computer system time. Yes?

Comment: @PaulAlexanderBurkart no it will get the default php timezone when done like that, which from memory is PST.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
// you need to find your timezone here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'); 

$date_obj = new DateTime("now", $timezone); 
$date_obj->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

$date = $date_obj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  

$sql = "INSERT INTO logs (ip, date, page) VALUES ('$ip', '$date', '$page')";
print $sql;
```

More on [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

You should really store dates as a **datetime** and not a string... Also, I would highly consider storing all dates as UTC, too.  This way, you always know exactly when something was done and it's not relative.  You can display the date back to the user in whatever timezone is appropriate.  If you want to make both of those chages, your query would turn into:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO logs (ip, date, page) VALUES ('$ip', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), '$page')";
```

Also, please note that with the other solutio posted here... `getdate()` is *not* a MySQL function, it is exclusively for SQL Server.   And if you include the quotes around any function name, MySQL will interpret the whole thing as a string and not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that date() is deprecated.

So, I personaly use strftime().

e.g. to get a time with micro second stamp:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello world!<br/>";
  echo "We are the ".strftime("%d %B %Y")."<br/>";
  echo "and it is now ".strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")." and ".(float)microtime()." ms.<br/>";
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `date()` is deprecated? Any source?

Comment: simply have the following statement in php.ini: error_reporting = E_ALL and you'll get a warning message if you use date()!